# How to use drag and drop feature of console application and streamreader

Tags: c#, console-application, streamreader

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = Console.ReadLine();
        using (StreamReader sr = new Streamreader(path);
        {
           \\ do something with the file
        }
    }
```

Hi, I'm trying to allow the user to drag and drag a txt file into the console, have it read the path, and then parse information from the file.

However I'm getting:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Illegal characters in path.

when I run my code. I think I can solve it by formatting the file path before using it, but that doesn't seem like the "intended solution". Is there somthign simple that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

When you drag a file onto the console application's `.exe` file, the path of that file is automatically made the first argument of the console application. So, you can get the path from that argument if it exists. You should also double-check that the argument contains a path (valid file name) in case the console application is started from the command line with other arguments.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length > 0 && File.Exists(args[0]))
    {
        string path = args[0];
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
           // do something with the file
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I want the user to drop into the Console directly, not the .exe. The File.Exists check is always returning false if I'm trying to read the file using ReadLine(), but when I write the file path back to the Console, it looks valid.

Comment: File.Exists(path.Substring(1, path.Length - 2)) returns what I want. I'm going to use this for now.